# Pass boolean value to a .Net Extension object

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XSL:

```
  <xsl:variable name="PriorityCall">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$PriorityFlag = 1 or $PriorityFlag = 2 or $PriorityFlag =3">
        <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
```

and I want to pass the value of PriorityCall into a .Net Extension Object as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="UCInterface:InsertNewGroup($UserRef, $SiteCode, $PriorityCall)" />
```

Signature of the .Net method:

```
public string InsertNewGroup(string userRef, string siteCode, bool prioritySite)
```

the value in .Net is always true. However I can pass false if I call the extension method like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="UCInterface:InsertNewGroup($UserRef, $SiteCode, false())" />
```

How can I pass a bool value by getting the value out of $PriorityCall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variable as `<xsl:variable name="PriorityCall" select="$PriorityFlag = 1 or $PriorityFlag = 2 or $PriorityFlag =3"/>`.

With your current setup your variable is (in XSLT 1.0) of type result tree fragment, a result tree fragment which contains a single, non empty text node which happens to contain the representation of a boolean value. But that will always be converted to true. If you simply use the `select` attribute with a boolean XPath expression, as shown above, then the value is of type boolean.